# need help converting this php mysql code to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have php code for an upload form, and am trying to update this mysql to the recommended mysqli. I am trying to learn the OO style (and also procedural, but am leaning towards learning the OO style).

I have been successful on updating all my codes so far, except for this snippet:

```
function query($query) {  
$database = $this->options['database'];  
$host = $this->options['host'];  
$username = $this->options['username'];  
$password = $this->options['password'];  
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);  
if (!$link) {  
    die(mysql_error());  
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);  
if (!$db_selected) {  
    die(mysql_error());  
}  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
mysql_close($link);  
return $result;  
}
```

Can anyone help me translate that into MySQLi, object oriented style? I tried so many combinations I don't know where I am going wrong (I am getting a db error when trying to upload a photo).

thanks!

Comment: Please add some code that you tried, error message received and we will try to help you by pointing out what's wrong with it..

Comment: For the most part, as far as the procedural style goes, you can just replace every instance of `mysql_` with `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. I'm not sure that a mysqli result will survive a mysqli->close() so I've retrieved the data from the $result into an array and returned that. You might want to test this.

I also wonder why you're opening the connection and closing it again around each query. I'd normally open the connection and leave it open until the script has finished all its queries.

```
function query($query) {  
  // no real need for this - the variables can be used directly
  $database = $this->options['database'];  
  $host = $this->options['host'];  
  $username = $this->options['username'];  
  $password = $this->options['password'];  

  // instantiate the mysqli object. Select the database at the same time.
  $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {  
    die($mysqli->connect_error);  
  }

 $result = $mysqli->query($query); 
 if ($result !== false) { 

   // retrieve data
   $data = array();
   while ($data[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}

   // release the result set and close the connection
   $result->free();
   $mysqli->close();
   return $data;
 } else {
   syslog(LOG_ERROR, "SQL error:".$mysqli->error);
   $mysqli->close();
   return false;       
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response (and commenting what you did, very much appreciated)... Although this code is allowing the photo to upload, and sending an email as well (a separate file, email triggered after upload), I am getting an "internal server error" on my upload page. I'm trying to figure out why it's saying that instead of showing success... I'll let you know if I find out... thanks again!

Comment: Look at your server logs - there should be an error message there that will explain the 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: thanks for that great idea... I cleared the log, tried the upload, and see this: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home1/nameofsite/public_html/jQueryFileUpload/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 818

Comment: and, btw... line 818 is: while ($data[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}

Comment: Hey Mike... thanks so much for your help, this did the trick (ohh, I just see you responded also, I will try that right now too), But, this worked: 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
}
return $result;
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
}

Comment: That sounds like your query has failed. My snippet wasn't checking for that. I've added a little extra code to write a message to the log file if the query fails - that should give you a clue - and return `false`. I didn't intend this to be production ready code - just a pointer to how to do it. You might have to do a little debugging of your own :)

Comment: thanks again, Mike... I appreciate you steering me in the right direction! I didn't have luck with your code, but I got it working (the final thing that made it work was putting "return $result;" before the free and close)... Anyways, you'll get my vote for helping me :) thanks!